# Removing lone, obsolete tags on offtopic questions

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we handle the situation where a question has only one tag, but the tag is obsolete and the question is off-topic? For example, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139898/when-server-fails) (10k-only), which is off-topic and didn't have any tags other than [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) until after it was brought up here on Meta.

Comment: I've retagged it with `concurrency`, `excel` and `dropbox`.

Comment: Looks like a perfect deletion candidate... maybe a kindly moderator / covey of 20k plus users will come along.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks. I never even thought of looking for a dropbox tag on here as it's way OT but I suppose if people are using the dropbox API or using it for storing source code I guess it could be legitimate.

Comment: If a closed question that is clearly off-topic can't be retagged, you can also flag for a moderator to delete it.

Comment: Any chance I could have this reopened please as I've de-localized it now?

Comment: We already have guidelines for handling obsolete tags and guidelines for handling closed questions. They don't contradict each other, so if you find a question that fits both descriptions, just follow both sets of guidelines. (I'll expand this into an answer if and when this question gets reopened.)

Comment: @PopularDemand It's not the face it is closed that is at issue but rather the fact the obsolete tag is the only tag and the question is offtopic. I have updated the title accordingly. Could you point me to the guidelines for handling obsolete tags please as I have searched meta and the FAQ and I can't find them.